# Finding the last modified/write time of a disk partition windows

Tags: python, windows, powershell, timestamp

I'm currently working on a **python** tkinter **windows-based** application where I need to get the **last modified time** of a **disk partition**. My main aim is to get the latest updated time of a partition, where the host system user might have created a file\folder and also deleted some files and there might be some other changes made by the user to some files. I have tried this using python `os.stat()` but it only provides the modified date of *existing files*, it **fails** in case of a *deleted file*. The same is the case with the PowerShell command `Get-ChildItem| Sort-Object -Descending -Property LastWriteTime | select -First 1`, it provides the last time with respect to the contents present in the main directory but does not handle the changes made for file\folder deletion.
In the application, I want to get the comparison of the partition state change, i.e. if the user has made some changes to the disk partition since the last use of the application. Another option to get this result is by calculating the hash value for the disk partition but that is much time consuming, I need to get the result in just a few seconds.

This is my first interaction on StackOverflow as a questioner. Looking forward to getting helpful answers from the community.

Comment: Have you looked at [auditing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/apply-a-basic-audit-policy-on-a-file-or-folder)?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, will look into this, thanks